# Redirect to different action depending on User Status

Tags: symfony, event-handling

I'm working with Symfony 2.1. I want to setup a redirect routine depending on User is logged in or not. The way I check it is `$User->isLoggedIn()` where `User` is a service.

I want to do this before a controller executes. I have few other things happening just before Controller executes. I use event: `kernel.controller` of `kernel.event_listener` to do those things. But I realized that I can not redirect to a URL using this event.

I understand I need to use event: kernel.request of kernel.event_listener to be able to redirect to a URL.

Problem. 
I use the following logic to figure out whether I need to redirect or not.

```php
if (!$controller[0] instanceof NoLogInNeededInterface) {

     if (!$User->isLoggedIn()) {
        //redirect here
     }
}
```

So, in the `kernel.request` event, `$controler[0]` is not available. In the `kernel.controller` event, response can't be set (will be ignored).

Has anyone got same problem and solved. Or is there any better way of doing, what I'm trying to do?

Comment: as a side tip: If you start with a new project, please use Symfony2.2. Symfony 2.0 is no longer maintained

Comment: Thanks. Have got 2.1 actually. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that what I wanted could be achieved by using kernel.exception event of kernel.event_listner.

So in Services:

```
my.service:
   class: MyBundle\EventListner\ExceptionListner
        tags:
           - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
        arguments: [ %logoutUrl% ]
```

Then in the Class itself:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class ExceptionListner
{
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event) {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        //dont necessarily need this condition
        if ($exception instanceof RedirectException) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->_url);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm still up for suggestion, if this is or is not better approach. 
Hope this will help someone who is struggling as well. 
P